# Question about dynamics n-t coordinate system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics, mechanical

et = tangential unit vector
en = unit vector in normal direction

I'm currently studying dynamics and I'm having difficulty understanding the process of obtaining det and det/dt in the n-t coordinate system.

In the major book, it is said that it is det and det / dt as shown in the picture below. However, I think that if et changes, both beta and en will change, but I don't understand why there is no derivative of en in det/dt.

If anyone knows more about the process of obtaining det and det/dt in the n-t coordinate system, please explain. In particular, please explain why the en term is not differentiable in det/dt.

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't the vectors always be orthogonal?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.